# git - "ignore" or avoid versioning subdirectories

Tags: linux, git, versioning, gitignore, ignore

I want to have all my configuration files versioned using Git in a remote repository at Github. I'm using Debian 7 testing, and all my configuration files are under the `/home/user_name/` directory.

I created the usual `.gitignore` with all the files that I want to ignore and the files and directories that I want to allow versioning. My problem begins when I go to Documents, for example, and I see in zsh that folder is under the same versioning as the home directory.

I understand that Git works that way, but I need to know if it's possible to avoid that.

Comment: Your question is not clearly formulated. Is it corect that you want to put your entire home directory under git version control and upload it to Github? I suggest that you rather use separate git repos for some selected directories.

Comment: No, I want to control with git the versions of specific files (gitconfig, vimrc, zshrc, etc ...) that I use in the home directory, no the sub directories. So, if I go to a subdirectory of the home directory, git automatically includes this directory in his "tree directory" to the version control. I don't want that. Clear now? :)

Comment: Ah, so you want to have version control over several files that are somewhere in your home, ignoring their specific paths. This is not possible and makes no sense: What do you do in case of two files with the same name?

Comment: Or, do you simply add your files in a wrong way, accidentally adding every other file in the directory as well?

Comment: You can use .gitignore to exclude also directories.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `/*/` entry in your `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

One classic way to version configuration files is to create a subdirectory like `~/etc/` and let your `~/.something` files be symbolic links to `~/etc/something`. Then, you can version `~/etc/` normally.

You can manage to ignore everything but your configuration files, but you'll always have little glitches like: the day you run `git clean -fdx` in the wrong place, you delete **all** your data.

Answer (score 0):

Write `*/` in your `.gitignore` to ignore directories.  Make exceptions with `!foodir`.  Consider prefixing with slashes (see documentation for details).